# How does VIM sets the $VIM environment variable?

Tags: environment-variables

I was reading http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#initialization, but couldn't immediately find the answer. Is the `$VIM` environment variable hardcoded in its binary (not read from a config file)? The binary is built differently depending on the OS, so I'm guessing that's how the `$VIM` differs per OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole process can be read under `:h $VIM`:

> To avoid the need for every user to set the $VIM environment variable,
> Vim will try to get the value for $VIM in this order:
>
> 1. The value defined by the $VIM environment variable.  You can use this to    make Vim look in a specific directory for its support
>    files.  Example:
>    setenv VIM /home/paul/vim
> 2. The path from 'helpfile' is used, unless it contains some environment    variable too (the default is
>    "$VIMRUNTIME/doc/help.txt": chicken-egg    problem).  The file name
>    ("help.txt" or any other) is removed.  Then    trailing directory
>    names are removed, in this order: "doc", "runtime" and
>    "vim{version}" (e.g., "vim54").
> 3. For MSDOS, Win32 and OS/2 Vim tries to use the directory name of the    executable.  If it ends in "/src", this is removed.  This is
>    useful if you    unpacked the .zip file in some directory, and
>    adjusted the search path to    find the vim executable.  Trailing
>    directory names are removed, in this    order: "runtime" and
>    "vim{version}" (e.g., "vim54").
> 4. For Unix the compile-time defined installation directory is used (see the    output of ":version").
>
> Once Vim has done this once, it will set the $VIM environment
> variable.  To change it later, use a ":let" command like this:
>
> ```
>     :let $VIM = "/home/paul/vim/"
> ```

It is sometimes hard to find stuff in the vim help "immediately" but it is a great source. The vim helpfile is a mighty tool which will guide you a long way before you need this site, once you got the hang of it!

Comment: To be fair, this info is kinda buried. Though if you were able to find your way to starting.txt it's not too much of a stretch to search for `$VIM`. `:helpgrep` helps (no pun intended), but then you have to know how to display and navigate the quickfix window. Vim is so unfriendly to beginners, I don't fault anyone for questions like this.

Comment: @BigMcLargeHuge I am sorry, I didn't intended to sound rude at all. I just wanted to hint the might of the vim help. Tried to adapt my answer, I hope it is clear now, that I was not at all angry about the question!

Answer (score 3):

Linux view, for more details see Doktor OSwaldo answer.

The installation directory is defined during build (to be exact: It is defined when configuring the build.). The default value of `$VIM` is a subdirectory below the installation directory and is compiled in (`<inst-dir>/share/vim` on Linux).

You can override this by setting the environment variable `VIM` before starting Vim.

The compiled-in value of `$VIM` is part of the output from `:version` or `vim --version`. Just search for `fall-back for $VIM`.

Within Vim you can display the actual value by executing

```
:echo $VIM
```

Comment: What I found quite confusing for the beginner is that after downloading and installing vim, you would normally expect it to know where it was installed, or at least to show a very prominent message saying "warning - it will not work properly until you have set this environment variable"

Comment: @Andy I don't understand. What won't work properly? Vim does know where it's installed and sets `$VIM` accordingly without any user intervention. This answer just describes how you might change it, though I'm not sure why you'd want to.

Comment: @Big McLargeHuge That's not what I understand from my experience and from @Ralf's answer, at least for people who downloaded vim rather than compiling it themselves. I installed a binary of vim on my Ubuntu 20.02 (I'm not sure exactly how but I'm guessing probably with apt). It installed into `/usr/share/vim/vim82` but the built-in VIM variable was set to `/usr/share/vim` so I had to override it in my .profile. I can't remember quite what it was that wasn't working, but I was trying to install plugins at the time and this definitely fixed the problem.